# Is it normal practice to code a protected variable as Uow or _uow in C#?

Tags: c#

I am coding an application that is similar to the Code Camper application. In this 
application I see the following code in a controller base:

```
public abstract class ApiControllerBase : ApiController
{
    protected ICodeCamperUow Uow { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller:

```
public class AttendanceController : ApiControllerBase
{
    public AttendanceController(ICodeCamperUow uow)
    {
        Uow = uow;
    }
```

I understand that it's normal to have parameters as lowercase in C# but is
it normal practice to name the Uow as in the above or would _uow which is 
what I have been using a naming convention that is more commonly adopted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming conventions in the sample look typical. The `_` prefix (like `_uow`), is typically used with *private fields*. There is no private field here; `Uow` is a property, and it's protected, not private.

And again, these are just common conventions. There is nothing in the language to enforce this, and a particular project may depart from this at the discretion of the development team.

Comment: Cohhoorn. Thanks. Just to clarify. If you were to code this. Would you use a convention of Uow ?

Comment: Yes, I would use might, if I knew what Uow meant. I like to think I'd use something more easily understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about default style as covered on MSDN [Capitalization Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Since it is property it should use PascalCase, if it would be field it should use lowerCase.

Note that the name does not seem to follow [Abbreviations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/141e06ef%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) suggestion.

Overall if your codebase follows particular coding guideline and everyone is happy with it - follow the same. For public samples consider following default C# guideline (full word names, no prefixes/underscores, proper casing).

Answer (score 0):

As a generic [guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from Microsoft themselves for c++, c#, etc

**Do not** use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters.
It's subjective in my opinion, conventions aren't hard and fast rules, most important is the consistency.